# NFS Mount Permissions on External Drive

Tags: terminal, external-disk, mount

I use [Vagrant](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant) to manage Virtualbox instances and up until a few OS versions ago was able to sync drives from an external drive. (On `12.3.1` now.)

Other vagrant users are also [struggling with this](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/12330), and I'm seeing posts going back to 2013 that address NFS on OS X, some of which mention the `/etc/fstab` (File System Tab), which apparently doesn't exist by default doesn't seem to have a lot of Apple-specific documentation. Here's a [(Linux) reference on How-To-Geek](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/38125/htg-explains-what-is-the-linux-fstab-and-how-does-it-work/).

NOTE: I have added NFSD (and iTerm) to Full Disc Access in System Preferences > Security & Privacy.

*An* example of an [OS X/macOS ftab file on github](https://gist.github.com/threebytesfull/968327) states:

```
# You can find the volume UUID in Disk Utility. Select the volume on the left
# and then File->Get Info. See "Universal Unique Identifier".
#
# Options used below:
#  ro for readonly (can be omitted)
#  noauto to prevent auto-mount
#  noatime to skip writing last access times (performance thing, optional)
#
# Remember to set the filesystem type (hfs, ntfs, etc) too
```

There's also a comment mentioning a utility, `vifs`, specifically for editing the `ftab` file (`$ sudo vifs`). In my case this results in a warning:

> ## Warning - this file should only be modified with vifs(8)

(What does the `(8)` mean?)

Between Disk Utility (for reference) and this terminal command: `diskutil info -all |grep -e "Device Node" -e "Proto" -e "UUID" -e "Mount Point" -e "Type"`, I have:

```
Device Node:               /dev/disk3s1
Volume Name:               Oggun
Mount Point:               /Volumes/Oggun
Type (Bundle):             hfs
Protocol:                  USB
Volume UUID:               C9AEED83-EB14-3C9F-97D5-D95A0252F9EF
```

Guessing that I need to add a line along the lines of:

```
# DRIVE with DIRECTORY to MOUNT via NFS
UUID=0C9AEED83-EB14-3C9F-97D5-D95A0252F9EF  /Volumes/Oggun  hfs rw,auto
```

I *think* the third column, contains the "type" of drive.

Hoping someone more informed than me will be inspired to share with some real insight.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to my problem. It doesn't involve `/etc/fstab` and not really "permissions" either, but will share for posterity:

The sources are [Roots.io, discourse](https://discourse.roots.io/t/big-sur-update-vagrant-not-mounting-folders-on-external-drives/21020/3) and a corresponding [github issue](https://github.com/roots/trellis/issues/1210#issuecomment-884011080).

In my `etc/exports` file:

```
"/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/External_Storage" -alldirs -mapall=502:20 192.168.50.52
"/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Storage" -alldirs -mapall=502:20 192.168.50.39
"/System/Volumes/Data/Volumes/Storage" -alldirs -mapall=502:20 192.168.50.85

... vagrant blocks can be removed
```

Where `192.168.50.xx` are the IP addresses set in various vagrant instances.

Then in the Vagrant file, wherever you are setting synced_folders, you set  vagrant's `nfs_export` flag to `false`, which can be done by within a `vagrant.default.yml` by adding `vagrant_nfs_export: false` and then within **Vagrantfile** where there are `synced_folder` settings, add:

```
nfs_export: vconfig.fetch('vagrant_nfs_export', false)
```

Then restart the **nfs deamon**: `sudo nfsd restart`.